# Problems with TimeMachine configuration - can I blow this away and start over?

Tags: installation, osx-lion, time-machine, migration

I am migrating from a MacBook Pro (early 2009 - OSX 10.6.8) to a new MacBook Pro (OSX 10.7.2). I have been backing up to an external drive using TimeMachine.

I want to migrate the back up to my new laptop but jumped the gun and can't get TimeMachine to ask for a backup location (see Dan Moren's article – [Migrate Time Machine backup to new Mac in Lion](http://www.macworld.com/article/161421/2011/07/migrate_time_machine_backup_to_new_mac_in_lion.html))

Questions:

1. Is there a way to force Time Machine to ask for a backup location so I can point it to the old existing files, or
2. Can I blow away the Time Machine settings and start over with it without having to also wipe my drive and start over with a new system install?

Comment: So what exactly did you do by "jumping the gun"? What happens when you plug in the disk, and/or try to start a Time Machine backup?